# FInd a control s value inside a table in tr

Tags: javascript

I have this table and I want to find a hidden control's value inside the `tr` .

I tried this javascript

```
function DeleteGridview_Row(pid) {
  alert(pid);
  var table = document.getElementById('<%= gvResults_gov.ClientID %>');
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var i;
  var j;
  var cells;
  var customerId;
  for (i = 0, j = rows.length; i < j; ++i) {
    cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    if (!cells.length) {
      continue;              }
      customerId = cells[0].innerHTML;
    }
    alert(customerId);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="4" style="color: #333333; border-width: 0px; border-style: Groove;
    width: 100%; font-weight: bold; width: 100%;" id="MainContent_gvResults_gov"
    class="box-table-b">
    <tbody>

        <tr >
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="6532" id="MainContent_gvResults_gov_hdDocID_0" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvResults_gov$ctl02$hdTocID">
            </td>
            <td>
                1010041215
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please remove the "enter code here"

Answer (score 2):

1. remove the `enter code here`
2. if the code is complete you need an ending }

If the customer ID is 1010041215 you need the second cell (from 0)

```
for (i = 0, j = rows.length; i < j; ++i) {
  cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (!cells.length) {
    continue;              }
    customerId = cells[1].innerHTML; // [1] is the second cell
  }
}
```

change

```
   customerId = cells[1].innerHTML; // [1] is the second cell
```

to

```
    customerId = cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
```

if you want the value of the input field

However tables have rows and cells:

```
function DeleteGridview_Row(pid) {
  var customerId = "";
  var table = document.getElementById('<%= gvResults_gov.ClientID %>');
  var rows = table.rows;
  for (i = 0, n = rows.length; i < n; ++i) {
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    if (!cells.length) {
      continue;              }
      customerId = cells[1].innerHTML;
    }
  }
  return customerId;
}
```